# How to improve scrollbar look / integration in design with sticky right column using CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, web

I have implemented a layout using css Grid.

The left column should only scroll and the right one should be sticky or fixed.
It's working fine but the scrollbar break the design.

Can scrollbar be removed or any other solution?

I know that is native of the browser but what can I do? (I also tried to change the design but its now supported by Firefox)

[image]

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "list content";
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  color: white;
}
.container .list {
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: list;
  background-color: #131418;
  padding: 20px;
}
.container .list .items {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.container .content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: #15161b;
  padding: 15px;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="list">
  <h5>
  Items
  </h5>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <small>User name</small>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id efficitur arcu. Mauris ut nulla id lorem tempor malesuada id quis libero. Duis ornare massa at ex sodales blandit. 
      </p>
      <small>Made by ...</small>
    </div>
     <div class="item"  style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <small>User name</small>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id efficitur arcu. Mauris ut nulla id lorem tempor malesuada id quis libero. Duis ornare massa at ex sodales blandit. 
      </p>
      <small>Made by ...</small>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>
  Hello world
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id efficitur arcu. Mauris ut nulla id lorem tempor malesuada id quis libero. Duis ornare massa at ex sodales blandit. 
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may try to use `position: sticky;` in your CSS

Comment: Yes, I’m already using position: sticky for the content

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to improve scrollbar's look.

Take a look at
[perfect-scrollbar](http://utatti.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) for example.
Perfect-scrollbar will only be displayed when mouse is hover related DIV.

**Demo screenshot**
[image]
(Look at the right very tiny scrollbar)

**[author's JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/utatti/dyvL31r6/)**

```
var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.container');
```

**Your code snippet resolved**

```js
var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.list');
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "list content";
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  color: white;
}
.container .list {
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: list;
  background-color: #131418;
  padding: 20px;
}
.container .list .items {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.container .content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: #15161b;
  padding: 15px;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/dist/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="list">
  <h5>
  Items
  </h5>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <small>User name</small>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id efficitur arcu. Mauris ut nulla id lorem tempor malesuada id quis libero. Duis ornare massa at ex sodales blandit. 
      </p>
      <small>Made by ...</small>
    </div>
     <div class="item"  style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <small>User name</small>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id efficitur arcu. Mauris ut nulla id lorem tempor malesuada id quis libero. Duis ornare massa at ex sodales blandit. 
      </p>
      <small>Made by ...</small>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>
  Hello world
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id efficitur arcu. Mauris ut nulla id lorem tempor malesuada id quis libero. Duis ornare massa at ex sodales blandit. 
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but it's not working. I added successfully the library but I still seeing the white scrollbar

Comment: For some reason it's just working on specific screen sizes, because if I'm with "inspect element" window opened looks fine, but If I'm on full screen then white scrollbar appears